# Select Statement in Talend using REGEXP (MYSQL) to find spaces in a first name field

Tags: mysql, regex, talend

writing a select statement to view first names with spaces in them i.e. JO ANN or TERRY LYNN,

my statement format would look like:

```
SELECT FirstName FROM `DB`.`TABLE` where FirstName REGEXP ' '
```

I know the names exist because I can see them in the preview i just need to write a select statement to only view the names with spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use POSIX class which matches all the space characters because your's won't match the names which has tabs.

```
SELECT FirstName FROM `DB`.`TABLE` where FirstName REGEXP '[[:space:]]'
```

This would match the names only if there exists a space between two alphabets.

```
SELECT FirstName FROM `DB`.`TABLE` where FirstName REGEXP '[[:alpha:]][[:blank:]]+[[:alpha:]]'
```

Comment: So this actually returned every name in the table, looks like every name may have a space after it

Comment: That's weird but possible. I would advice to print out the hex codes of the characters to make sure. MySql is not my dialect but something like select  hex(lastchar(col1)) from ... should be possible.

Comment: '[[:alpha]][[:blank:]]+[[:alpha:]]' returned an invalid char class error

Comment: i sadly have no control of the source data but it is looking like all empty spaces up to 40 chars are filled with "space"

Comment: '[[:alpha:]][[:blank:]]+[[:alpha:]]'  this worked!! thank you!